# What is the required procedure for a US resident to acquire a prescription drug from Canada?

Tags: prescription, health-informatics

Some drugs, such as Resolor (Prucalopride), are not available in the United States, yet doctors practicing in the United States use them for patients.  For example, Dr. Mark Pimentel, discussing his approach to IBS treatment, explains, "Generally we resort to two potential prokinetics.  One is erythromycin at a very low dose.  It has prokinetic properties at a very low dose and no antibiotic properties at that does, so that’s what we use.  Sometimes we get Resolor, which is prucalopride from Canada, a very potent prokinetic based on serotonin.  It doesn’t have any real side effects except for headache in some patients."  (https://chriskresser.com/sibo-update-an-interview-with-dr-mark-pimentel/)  Dr. Pimentel's practice is located in California, but Resolor is not available in the United States.

What steps must a patient/doctor pair in the United States go through to acquire such a drug, and how long is the process expected to take?